# T-SQL : How to output whitespaces with Substring on an empty column

Tags: t-sql, substring, whitespace, informix

I am trying to convert a Informix select query to T-SQL.

On a Date column thats in YYYYMMDD format, the Informix query has below Statusdate in Select and I wrote the equivalent T-SQL which works perfectly to output Statusdate in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Informix:

```
Date[1,4]||"-"||Date[5,6]||"-"||Date[7,8] as StatusDate
```

T-SQL:

```
SUBSTRING(Date,1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Date,5,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Date,7,2) AS StatusDate
```

But if the Date column is empty, the Informix output is [    -  -  ] i.e 4spaces-2spaces-2spaces
while SQL output is [--] i.e no white spaces.

How can I updated the T-SQL query to get output similar to Informix when column is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a `CASE` expression here to explicitly handle the output for `NULL` dates:

```sql
CASE WHEN Date IS NOT NULL
     THEN LEFT(Date, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Date, 5, 2) + '-' + RIGHT(Date, 2)
     ELSE '    -  -  ' END AS StatusDate
```

Comment: The Informix (standard SQL) `||` operator generates NULL if either of its arguments is NULL.  The described output means the column must be a blank string that is not null.

Comment: That is correct. The column is not NULL but empty. In anycase, I was able to use CASE statement as below and it works perfectly.

CASE WHEN Date = ''
     THEN '    -  -  ' 
     ELSE LEFT(Date, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Date, 5, 2) + '-' + RIGHT(Date, 2) END AS StatusDate